# error while upgrading from debian bullseye to bookwork

Tags: phpmyadmin, debian

`while upgrading from debian bullseye to bookworm, I get the following error:

```
    dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/bootstrap/jquery/images' not       owned by package 'phpmyadmin:all'
```

`
and many others errors of the same kind
I tried to --fix-broken, no success

I've no idea to solve it.
Please help.
many thanks in advance

Comment: Personally, I'd go for the brute force approach to this. `ls -lha /usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/bootstrap/jquery` and compare permissions, then use chown to fix it. It's probably not the best solution, but it's simple and quick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I just removed the theme with

```
sudo rm -r /usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/bootstrap/
```

And then it worked just fine.
Make sure you have another theme installed before doing that. But normally that should be the case.

```
ls -lha /usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/
```